# trying to store given inputs as a floyd triangle

Tags: java

```
    import java.util.*;
    public class triangle{
      public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner input_Obj = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of lines in the triangle");
        int sum = 0;
        int mat_size = input_Obj.nextInt(); //input of the size of the triangle
        System.out.println("enter the inputs");
        int input_Array[][] = new int[mat_size][mat_size];
        for (int row = 0; row < mat_size; row++){
        for (int col = 0; col < col; col++){
            input_Array[row][col] = input_Obj.nextInt();
        }
    }
        if (mat_size >= 3){
            int[] sum_array = new int[2*(mat_size-2)];
        for (int row = 1; row < mat_size; row++){
            for(int col = 0;col<=row;col++){
                sum += input_Array[row][col];  
            }
            sum_array[row-1] = sum;
        }
    }
        else if(mat_size == 2){
            if (input_Array[1][0]<input_Array[1][1]){
                System.out.println("minimum of the two elements in second      line is:" +input_Array[1][0]);
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("minimum of the two elements in second line is:" +input_Array[1][1]);
            }
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("minimum sum can't be calculated");
        }
    }
}
```

It is not storing values in the input array
It is taking the input in mat_size but not taking inputs into the array
I'm trying to find the minimum sum inside the triangle

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int col = 0; col < col; col++)
```

`col < col` this is the issue as condition is never satisfied that is why it is not taking any input, change this condition to

```
for (int col = 0; col < mat_size; col++)
```